# What is the easiest and fastest way of converting probabilities into prediction labels?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, classification, vectorization, logistic-regression

In short, I am looking for a one/two line code for following code:

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):

    # Convert probabilities A[0,i] to actual predictions p[0,i]
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 4 lines of code)
    if(A[i] > .5)
       Y_prediction[i] = 1
    else 
        Y_prediction[i] = 0
```

Comment: Add sample case with expected output?

Comment: Code from Andrew Ng's DL specialization...?

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert the probability values to 0-1 labels. The assignment `V_prediction[0, :] = A[0, :] > 0.5` should be enough for that; the boolean values `A[0, :] > 0.5` (True/False) will become numbers 1, 0 if the target array V_prediction is numeric. An example:

```
V_prediction = np.zeros((3, 10))
A = np.random.uniform(size=(3, 10))
V_prediction[0, :] = A[0, :] > 0.5
```

`V_prediction` is now (randomly)

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If all labels are integers, V_prediction could be declared with integer data type.

A more elaborate approach, which extends to more complex scenarios, is to use [numpy.piecewise](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html).

```
V_prediction[0, :] = np.piecewise(A[0, :], [A[0, :] > 0.5, A[0, :] <= 0.5], [0, 1])
```

Answer (score -2):

The numpy `argmax` function should come in handy here. Just pass your array as an argument to the `argmax` function and it'll give you the labels based on the probabilities.

For more, [see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).